# when my tasks are empty its give me an error need to put condition i guess

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

> Hi when my tasks are empty it's giving me an error of Object null I guess I need to put condition but can't figure it out how and where

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import AddTasksForm from "./AddTasks";
import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";
import database from '../firebase/firebase';
// import reducer from '../reducer';

const TasksList = () => {

    const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState({});
    const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
```

> here I guess need to put the condition can u help me out where should I do that

```
    const fetchTasks = () => {
       
        const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child('tasks');
        dbtasksWrapper.on('value', snap => {
            const tasks = snap.val();  
            setTaskList(tasks)
          });
        };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTasks();
    }, [tasks])

console.log('tasks');

    return(
        <div>
            <div>Todo List Items</div>
            <ul>
                {Object.values(taskList).map((task, index) => ( 
                <TaskItem
                    task={task}
                    index={index}
                />
                ))}
            </ul>

           <AddTasksForm/>

        </div>
    );
}
export default TasksList;
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
TasksList
src/components/TasksList.js:31
  28 | return(
  29 |     <div>
  30 |         <div>Todo List Items</div>
> 31 |         <ul>
     | ^  32 |             {Object.values(taskList).map((task, index) => ( 
  33 |             <TaskItem
  34 |                 task={task}

Answer (score 1):

Check for the condition in return

```
return(
        <div>
            <div>Todo List Items</div>
            <ul>
                {taskList !== null ? Object.values(taskList).map((task, index) => ( 
                <TaskItem
                    task={task}
                    index={index}
                />
                )) : ''}
            </ul>

           <AddTasksForm/>

        </div>
    );
```

Comment: thanks its working but in this when i click on remove tasks all tasks removed not that particular task

Comment: that seems to be a different issue overall

Comment: my be because first it was working fine but after adding that condition i getting this issueconst removeTask = (id) => {
        
            database.ref('tasks').remove().then(()=>{
                dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_TASK', id: id })
                console.log('removed');
                })
    } this is removetask code

Answer (score 0):

```
const tasks = snap && snap.val()||[];
```